# Exit loop when line is empty with getline

Tags: c, linux, unix

How can I exit the while loop when stdin line is empty?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    FILE* stream = popen("sort", "w");
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t size;

    while (getline(&line, &size, stdin)) {
        fprintf(stream,"%s\n", line);
    }

    pclose(stream);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried checking the length of line and checking if `getline != -1` and it doesn't work.

Comment: getline returns -1 on error or EOF `while (-1) {}` will run forever.

Comment: Oh, I see, and how can I check if a line is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is the newline you read.

if you add

```
if (*line == '\n') break;
```

to your loop, it will probably work as intended.
Testing getline() for a -1 return value is a good idea; you might encounter an End Of File instead of an empty line